# Disabling @Scheduled methods/beans in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In my application I have 2 beans which have methods annotated with `@Scheduled` annotation. Sometimes I need to schedule both the methods, and sometimes I need to schedule either one of them, based on the input arguments to the application. How can I disable the @Scheduled method after it has been loaded? I am using Spring 3.1 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest instead of using @Schedule you should use TaskScheduler to schedule your job based on user input, this way you will have more control over execution, different implementation is provided by spring refer to [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) and scheduling [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)

Comment: yea this is much better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` into your application and call

```
taskScheduler.getScheduledExecutor().shutdown();
```

But remember, this is a hack. So I suggest using `TaskScheduler` directly without `@Scheduled` annotations.